# Do I need an "it" at the end of this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Tonight there were as many as grains of sand, a boundless cosmic
>   beach, with a black ocean stretching infinitely behind (it).

Why and why not?

I get both instances on Google:

> ... it is a likeable geometry that covers up a mystery stretching
>   **infinitely behind it** (but science hates a mystery). [[Source]](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEAQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fepc.buffalo.edu%2Fe-poetry%2F2011%2Fpapers%2Fhuber_atm_epoetry.pdf&ei=5D1AVbrTDIPDmwXXsICgBA&usg=AFQjCNG73r2FxASayuDsYyQmoWkBcU9aWg&sig2=4qxq1vXAe4YZVikMBRYJNA)
>
> It's right on an unknown, barely visited beach with the estuary
>   lapping within yards of the door and meadows **stretching infinitely
>   behind**. [[Source]](https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEYQFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com%2Flifeandstyle%2F2006%2Fjun%2F17%2Fhomes4&ei=5D1AVbrTDIPDmwXXsICgBA&usg=AFQjCNEopujPqAQHe3PVlbUjZU7BBg_oaQ&sig2=Au-Zdgc0_kt4Gow0x3IE4A)

Comment: You should add links to the examples you found, not a search results page.

Comment: @user3169 How about now?

Comment: In traditional English grammar, this would be the difference between the prep. *behind* and the adv. *behind*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tonight there were as many as grains of sand, a boundless cosmic beach, with a black ocean stretching infinitely behind (it).

First case scenario:

Omitting it, you get the adverb **behind** that modifies the verb stretching. Where is the ocean stretching? Behind.

Second case scenario:

Using it, **behind** functions as a preposition that sits before the pronoun **it** (which replaces **the beach**) and shows its relationship with the **ocean**.